# Safety Measures for Scripted File Deletion

Tags: c++, windows

I have a game engine and one of the features of the engine is the ability to write/overwrite files. For instance, when a user saves a map in the map editor. I am afraid of the case where a user accidentally saves their map over some other file, which may be easier than it sounds and even prone to some exploits by malevolent actors.

If I just had some way to tell my game "Hey, never, ever save/overwrite a file outside of the game's directory, which contains all the files you should ever worry about.", that would make me feel a lot better about releasing it. Does such a feature exist?

To overwrite an important file on windows, I think that a user would have to put ".." in the filename, to go back directories into other game data, or critically, files which aren't even part of the game. So, if I just check for that alone, will that be enough to protect the user?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even consider soft/hard links, but that would be worth addressing as I could imagine bad actors exploiting that too.

Comment: Many applications open a dialog box about an overwrite warning.  Maybe use that?

Comment: I totally forgot about that, and when I demo'd an "injection" attack I ran into the overwrite warning, so that's a very good point.

Comment: Also, using unique file types can make it pretty unlikely that anyone could run into this problem, I think.

Comment: Who are the "malevolent actors"? It's my computer, I can overwrite what I want and accept the consequences.

Comment: The engine is designed for people to make maps, with all their assets, and then possibly share them by dragging folders. If I ever make a website for people to share maps, I'm guessing there will be troll maps that delete your save or rename your character to offensive words, or things like that. But, if someone made a map titled with "../../../Pictures/doggo.png", foreseeably if the player edited that map they might end up overwriting a personal file. (maps have their own file type, so that helps, but I wish I could prevent this entirely.) The map could even encourage the user to edit it.

Comment: @EricBishop If a map is titled  "../../../Pictures/doggo.png" then it's fine. It's just a title, an internal name. They can't use .. or slashes (back or forward) in filenames. If they overwrite their own files, it was prolly intentional, as you can't really expect someone to use .. and / or \ unless they want to. Also, I don't think you can disable using .. and \ or / in the save or load dialogs, since they are used for navigation. Maybe you can make your own custom Save or Load windows that has a hardcoded project-only path. But it seems to much work just for some users that are "not smart".

Comment: Agh, I didn't even realize that, awesome! On windows I am able to put ".." in a file, but not "/\" so saving maps should be pretty safe.

Answer (score 1):

I would [`std::filesystem::canonical`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) both the map directory, and the user-provided path. Then check that the latter starts with the former, and then has a slash.

As always with `std::filesystem`, make sure to check Unicode handling on all platforms you're interesting in. E.g. Windows requires you to set an UTF-8 locale for some operations to work, such as converting the path to and from `std::string` as opposed to `std::wstring`.

Comment: Nice approach to most of the issues. Also, the new standard is cross-platform if he decides to migrate the engine. +1

Comment: IIRC `std::filesystem` on MSVC can handle `std::wstring` filenames, without using UTF-8.

Comment: @MSalters Mhm, but when you call `.string()` on the resulting path, it outright throws. I believe the reverse (constructing such path from a narrow string) also throws. `u8...` versions of those functions work, or setting the locale. I'll tweak the wording a bit.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: That's why you have `.native()`. I'm pretty sure that the reverse does not throw; constructs like `configDir/"config.xml"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Mostly no.

There are many apps that "detect" outside tampering, MSVS and N++ being most on-point to your situation. The way these apps work is they monitor the LUD (last updated date) of the file and if it is different to what they "remember", then it means it was modified externally. Proper apps have a very flexible workflow: you can ignore external changes and carry on with what you have in your app (so you lose external modifications) or reload (so you lose what the app has, but you "get" the external modification).

Another approach if you "don't care" for real-time monitoring catch events, such as Saving. When you save it, the same pop-up can give the user an option to either use the external payload or the one inside the app. Obviously "smart" apps also have a compare, merge or both as options (such as repository or versioning apps) on top of the earlier ones.

This would be the cross-platform approach. For "security" your best bet is on Windows because of the way it's designed: in most cases (random statistic incoming) 90% of the apps lock the files. That way, any modification from external apps is impossible. The downside is that if your engine is similar to Unity or Unreal, then there is a chance that a file can be edited both inside a utility or editor (for example file attributes inside the workspace or project, params or even editing internally, like for code files such as scripts or shaders), but also externally (such as map files, textures and so on).

This might impact the user experience though, more than it can help, so if you want to implement this, at least give the user an opt-in setting per project. Don't enforce it. The reason I say this is that a best practice is to just use a repository or versioning tool to take care of back-ups. Or even better, your engine / editor / tool / utility can include an auto-backup feature. You can even go crazy and add extra settings such as, if you do revert to an earlier backup version, to also save the current one so to not lose it (for example in the case of accidental overwrites). This would be easier then locking files.

Also note, if you *do* decide to go on the locking route, I am not sure this can be achieved on *nixes such as Linux or Mac if you'd decide to make your engine cross-platform. Considering that disks (either HDDs or SDDs) have tons of storage, giving the user an option to have 100000 versions of the same file might not be that bad, as long as you have a good directory structure and some proper logging as well as having the backup workflow properly explained. You prolly guessed I am mostly aiming at avoiding locking files.

Unity uses the timestamp monitoring as well, having some extra settings on top in the `*.meta` files (containing not only file data, but also properties you set in the editor and prolly more, depending on the file or data type).

So, TLDR: use timestamps for real-time monitoring, also use events to warn about losing external data (in case it's intentional on the user's side), use an auto-backup feature as well as some nice-to-have features as previously described to not lose the current file in case of rollbacks and encourage the use of repositories and versioning.

As for threat actors, I am not sure what the scenario you are thinking of. There are engines that would use scripts for some more "magic" (it's not encouraged and yes, I know Unreal does that, but it is so so so so annoying and unsecure), even enterprise companies do it internally on bought or in-house engines. I can just assume you would thinking of open sourcing your engine and putting some scripts on github and some trolls overwriting the scripts to cause havoc. The only way to do this would prolly be some hashing method to check that the downloaded files are the same as on the server (such as github). But since checking needs to be done manually, if you want an automated test that means you either make another script (which defies the point), or you make a dedicated exe to check it.

But again, it doesn't protect users 100% since project files can have scripts run on build events so someone can just tamper there.

Bottom line, users need to protect themselves using best-practice methods. You can't protect people if they are lazy. Just put warnings, recommendations and suggestions and it should be enough. Otherwise you'd end up in the other extreme and just ask remote access to all users and check everything yourself to make sure their computer is safe :) Keep in mind banks do the same thing. They make all kinds of suggestions and take as many precautions as they can, but in the end, the customer is responsible for his/her accounts and transactions. If a fraud happens because the user is naive and has no protection such as an AV or FW, or if the customer just does whatever a fraudster says (think of the Nigerian Prince scam) it is not the bank's fault.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! My account is a bit too new to upvote.

Comment: @EricBishop If it's (what you mostly) want, you can also mark it as an accepted answer if what I wrote is the route you wanna take.
Also, consider HolyBlackCat's approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649447/1115019 . Perhaps you can combine our two answers.

Comment: I don't think I did a good job of asking my question. Basically, when I save a map, the program appends "maps_dir" + nameOfMap + ".mapfile" and saves that to the local directory. I want to know if there's anyway to stop someone from injecting some stuff into their map's name, and into that directory, so that when the map is saved it writes over some files, e.g. by using "..", which I block, or perhaps by using a symlink, which I guess I could check against with std::filesystem::is_symlink() meticulously.
But, your answer answered other questions which I also have, so I'm very grateful :D

Comment: I already mentioned that part. You could do that if Windows lets you check the Load Save window's path (I don't use the UI part of the WINAPI, but from the few times I did, I think I could, but can't tell you 100% as it was around 15 years ago or so) or making your own Load / Save dialog, but I don't think it's worth it. I also said a lot of people use .. to navigate, including myself. So you could at most let someone do that *IF* the result is a path, not a file (but it seems you want to be strict and not allow this as well). What other information do you need?